# Why does it suffice to consider only increasing indices to define the basis of $\Lambda^k(T^*_pU)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tensor-products, differential-forms

I am studying differential $k$-forms from Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds*. If $(U, x^1, \ldots,x^n)$ is a coordinate chard for a manifold, then the dual basis for the cotangent space is given by
$$(dx^1)_p, \ldots, (dx^n)_p.$$
He states that by an earlier proposition, the basis for the alternating $k$-tensors in $\Lambda^k(T^*_pU)$ is given by
$$(dx^{i_1})_p \wedge\cdots\wedge(dx^{i_k})_p, \quad 1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n.$$
In the section where he introduces the mentioned proposition (where he is only focusing on $\mathbb{R}^n$), he states that

> A $k$-linear function $f$ on a real vector space $V$ is completely determined by its values on all $k$-tuples $(e_{i_1}, \cdots, e_{i_k})$. If $f$ is alternating, then it is completely determined by its values on $(e_{i_1}, \cdots, e_{i_k})$ with $1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n$; that is, it suffices to consider $e_I$ with $$I = (i_1, \ldots, i_k)$$ in strictly ascender order.

I was could not figure out why the above suffices.

Comment: The exterior product anticommutes ($x \wedge y = - y \wedge x$), so given a wedge product of a basis in any order you can reorder it by repeatedly anticommuting. It also satisfies $x \wedge x = 0$, so you only need to consider distinct indices.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you.